# Organizing tasks review (inspection, verification) in Jira

Tags: jira, code-injection

I'm new to Jira and I'm currently using it in a software development project. And one of the activities on the project is a code review process. A developer creates a new code and then two or more other developers (usually senior developers) inspect that code.

I'm thinking of a way to organize this process in Jira.

The Code Review task is logically a sub-task of the main task (a sub-task of a task). So making the code review task to be a sub-task mean we can't create sub-tasks in it, and that means we can only assign one reviewer.

I'd like to know is there an approach to conducting code review (i.e. a kind of inspection, verification of the work done) process in Jira?

Answer (score 0):

You can e.g. represent it in a workflow (see e.g. [here](https://cdn-images-1.medium.com/max/1600/1*vFvv0F24hrzlf66YLy-ajQ.png))

You can create a state for Review1 and one state for Review2. But if you want to have dynamic number of reviews, this will not work.